# Given a integer N>0, how many integers in the interval [0, 2^N) have exactly N-1 set bits? Write a short function that returns the correct answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, integer, byte

I wrote some C++ code to solve this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

unsigned int countSetBits(unsigned int n) 
{   
    int totalCount = 0, i;
    int cond = n-1;
    for(i=0;i<pow(2,n);i++){
        unsigned int count = 0; 
            while (i) { 
                count += i & 1; 
                i >>= 1; 
            }  
        if(count == cond){
            totalCount++;
        }

    }
    return totalCount; 
} 

int main()
{
    int n=5;
    cout<<countSetBits(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Although it is compiling succesfully, it doesn't print anything.
I can't figure out where is the problem...

Comment: `pow(2,n)` -- Don't use `pow` for integer exponents.  Also, when you used your debugger, when did you detect that the `while` loop terminated?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Extending on  Paul's comment, when you are working in exponents of two, use the left shift operator (<<). `1<<n` =>  2 to the power off `n`. For any other integer usually multiplication works out faster and safer.

Comment: i dont think you are supposed to use brute force. how many bits are set in `(2^N)-1`?

Comment: Search the internet for "bit twiddling" for some algorithm assistance.

Comment: You are calculating the limit of the `for` loop each iteration.  I recommend you calculate the limit once and store into a constant temporary variable.

Answer (score 4):

Pen and paper solution:

```
N=2  2^N-1 = 0b11    Possible integers with 1 bit set:
01
10
```

```
N=3  2^N-1 = 0b111   Possible integers with 2 bits set:
011
101
110
```

```
N=4  2^N-1 = 0b1111  Possible integers with 3 bits set:
0111
1011
1101
1110
```

So, `N` seems to be the answer.

Comment: Great answer, Ted - but I think the OP is expected to write a function that **calculates** the answer - even though: `unsigned int countSetBits(unsigned int n) { return n; }` gives the right answer!!

Comment: Perhaps, but "_Write a short function that returns the correct answer_" doesn't say as much :-)

Comment: This is a good answer. It would be a great answer if you mentioned that N is the number of bit positions the only 0 can be placed (which generalises for `k` 1s using binomial coefficients).

Comment: @rici Is that a conclusion you'd expect anyone doing the pen-and-paper exercise I demonstated would come to?  The first part **is** covered in my answer, right?

Comment: @ted: i'd hope they came to that conclusion without pen and paper, but the pen and paper list makes the diagonal quite evident. So, yes.

Comment: @rici Ok, but I purposely kept this two dimensional to be able to keep the answer short and to the point. I'm not convinced that what you suggest would make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the 'control' variable (`i`) of your `for` loop inside that loop, so that the value of `i` will never reach the loop limit and it will run forever.

To fix this, take a copy of the current `i` value and modify that:

```c
unsigned int countSetBits(unsigned int n)
{
    int totalCount = 0, i;
    int cond = n - 1;
    int limit = pow(2, n); /// Calculate this ONCE, rather than on each loop!
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        unsigned int count = 0;
        int j = i; /// Take a copy of i here (otherwise it will keep getting reset to zero)...
        while (j) { /// ...and do your test on the copy!
            count += j & 1;
            j >>= 1;
        }
        if (count == cond) {
            totalCount++;
        }
    }
    return totalCount;
}
```

There are also other improvements you can make, as mentioned in the comments. But the code changes I have posted at least fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You modify `i` inside the loop. The inner while loop will always make `i == 0`, no matter what the loop counter is, hence the condition for the for loop will never be false. Use a temporary. Also don't use `pow` to calculate powers of `2`. `2^N` is `(1 << N)`.

You need `N+1` bits to represent `2^N`. `(2^N)-1` has the `N` lower bits set. There are `N` possible bits to unset in `(2^N)-1`, hence there are `N` numbers with `N-1` bits set in `[0,2^N)`. qed ;)

```
unsigned int countSetBits(unsigned int n)  { return n; }
```